# scp command password problem

Tags: 14.04, password, scp

I am new to Ubuntu. I have two scaleway servers A and B. I need to transfer a file from A to B. I am using:

```
scp root@IP(A):/path/to/file root@IP(B):/path/of/destination
```

Upon executing the command it asked for password of A. After typing the correct password it returns an error:

> Permission denied, please try again.

I log in as `ssh admin@IP` for both servers. Can anyone guide me to the solution.

Comment: I have even checked the path where the file is transferred which is having correct permission for typical file transfer. And upon typing the password many times it will error `Connection to IP closed by remote host.`

Comment: In what way do you think the information that you can login as `admin@IP` is relevant to trying to login as `root@IP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the copy through your local host (`-3` switch):

```
scp -3 admin@IP(A):/path/to/file admin@IP(B):/path/of/destination
```

The previous commands do authentication and host key verification to the second host from the first remote and if is more fail-prone.

Comment: I have done the same. Still its asking for password!

Comment: And `ssh admin@IP` does not?

Comment: Even `ssh admin@IP` is asking for password.

Comment: So you probably need to enter one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current information you should replace `root` with `admin` in your call:

```
scp admin@IP(A):/path/to/file admin@IP(B):/path/of/destination
```

Comment: I did, its showing `Host key verification failed.
lost connection`

Comment: That means you have a conflicting host public key in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. If you are sure you are connecting to a legitimate server, you should locate which line conflicts with the current server key and remove it (you need to read the error message). Or temporarily add `-o stricthostchecking=no`.

Comment: But in `/known_hosts` file all the entries are in encrypted form. How will i know the current server key?

Comment: They are not encrypted, these are the keys. Read the error message!